# SQL query to pair together two individuals

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to pair together one person with code 111 and one person with code 222 **for the same date**.

```
Name          Code    Date
Joe Doe        111    2020-04-01
Jane Dane      222    2020-04-02 
Billy Bob      111    2020-04-02
Lame Jame      222    2020-04-01
```

From the example table: 
Joe Doe (111 and date 2020-04-01) should be paired with Lame Jame (222 and same date as Joe Doe), 
Jane Dane (222 and date 2020-04-02) should be paired with Billy Bob (111 and same date as Jane Dane)

How do I write an MS Access SQL query to acheive this? 
I believe there should be some kind of subquery with UNION and / or JOIN but I cannot make it work.

Comment: May I suggest you add your query attempts to your post as well? (Access has an option to show/edit the plain-text SQL code of your queries. You can copy and paste them.) In the mean time, I could give you the tip for looking into a so-called "self join" query to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a  "self join query". Thanks to Bart Hofland for hinting this.

```
SELECT Pairs.Name_, Pairs_1.Name_, Pairs.Code, Pairs_1.Code, Pairs.Date_ FROM Pairs, Pairs AS Pairs_1 WHERE (((Pairs.Code)='111') AND ((Pairs_1.Code)='222') AND ((Pairs.Date_)=[pairs_1].[Date_]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t1.name, t2.name, t1.date, t1.code
from t as t1 inner join
     t as t2
     on t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.code = t2.code and
        t1.name < t2.name
```

Comment: @Johnny . . . Then you should close the question.